# Android: Processing dialog box shown during scan wifi in process

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'd like to add a dialog processing box while scanning wifi until the result stored into receiver List, (1)how should i do that, and (2)how i identify the result in receiver ready to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class loading_box extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ProgressDialog pdialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
pdialog.setCancelable(true);
pdialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
pdialog.show();
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```